# How can I convert USD into the right wei for an eth transaction?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I'm getting like 18 billion dollar transactions, my items are priced in USD so I just need to send the right wei for that I guess.

```
 value: web3.utils.toWei(usdAmount, 'ether'),
```

I've tried helper methods like

```
function usdToWei(usdAmount, ethToUsdExchangeRate) {
  const weiPerEth = 10 ** 18; // 1 ETH = 10^18 wei
  const amountInEth = usdAmount / ethToUsdExchangeRate;
  const amountInWei = amountInEth * weiPerEth;
  return amountInWei;
}
```

But I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ethToUsdExchangeRate` is a `Number` type in JavaScript that holds the current price of 1 ETH in USD including decimals (e.g. $1234.56 is  stored as `1234.56`):

```
const ethToUsdExchangeRate = 1234.56;
const usdAmount = 10;

const oneUsdInWei = (10**18) / ethToUsdExchangeRate;
const usdAmountInWei = oneUsdInWei * usdAmount;

// returns 8100051840331779 wei (or ~0.008 ETH)
console.log(usdAmountInWei);
```